# Radar Installation UVA

Tags: c++, algorithm, greedy

I am trying to understand a sample solution for UVA problem 1193:

Problem statement:

[image: UVA 1193 - Radar Installation]

The solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

#define Max 10000
const double eps = 1e-10;

struct Interval {
    double st, en;
    Interval() {}
    Interval(double s, double e) {
        st = s, en = e;
    }
    bool operator < (const Interval &i) const {
        return (i.en == en) ? (st < i.st) : (en < i.en);
    }
};
long double x[Max], y[Max];
Interval inter[Max];

//bujhlam na baal
int main(void) {
    int n, d, testcase = 0;
    while(scanf("%d %d", &n, &d) == 2 && !(n == 0 && d == 0)) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            scanf("%Lf %Lf", &x[i], &y[i]);
        int count = 0, ok = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(d < y[i]) { // if island is out of radar radious
                ok = false; // that means at least one of the islands is not reachable results in -1
                break;
            } else {
                long double sqrtd = sqrt( d * d - y[i] * y[i] );
                inter[i] = Interval(x[i] - sqrtd, x[i] + sqrtd);
            }
        }
        if(!ok) {
            printf("Case %d: %d\n", ++testcase, -1);
            continue;
        }
        sort(inter, inter + n);

        for(int i = 0; i < n;) {
            int j;
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(inter[j].st > inter[i].en)
                    break;
            }
            i = j;
            count++;
        }
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", ++testcase, count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to follow the author's approach to solving this problem. The part that got me stuck is shown below:

```
long double sqrtd = sqrt( d * d - y[i] * y[i] );
inter[i] = Interval(x[i] - sqrtd, x[i] + sqrtd);
```

It seems like the author is using Pythagoras theorem? I can't see the purpose of this.

Also, why is sorting being used?

```
sort(inter, inter + n);
```

Could someone please enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: The code is finding the "feasible intervals" for each island with pitagoras. If interval is "imaginary", the island is not reachable. If Interval is `0`, the island is on the limit. If interval is `d`, the island is just aside the coast. Then, he sort those intervals -i.e. from far from close-, and for each island, it choose the narrow interval inside its own interval.  IT is tricky but, problably, it works....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question:

```
long double sqrtd = sqrt( d * d - y[i] * y[i] );
inter[i] = Interval(x[i] - sqrtd, x[i] + sqrtd);
```

This is to calculate the range which we can put a radar that can cover island `i`.

```
            . (x,y)
           /|\
          / | \ d
 0 ______/__|__\________  
        A   x   B
```

So, look at above image, to cover an island at position (x,y), we can put a radar in the range from `x - (d^2 - y^2)` , to `x + (d^2 - y^2)`

Some explanation:

Call points A and B two points on the Ox axis that have distance to point (x,y) equals `d`, so we have a square triangle (A , (x,y) , (x,0)), use Pythagoras theorem, we can easily calculate the location of A and B

```
A = x - (d^2 - y^2)

B = x + (d^2 + y^2)
```

For your second question:

```
Also, why is sorting being used?

sort(inter, inter + n);
```

In order to cover all islands, we need to start to put radar from the island that farthest to the left and continue to the second farthest ,... until we cover all islands. So, we can do this process greedily, by putting the radar to the right end `x + (d^2 - y^2)` of the first island, which can help to cover maximum number of islands on the right of this island, and continue this process with the next uncovered island until the end.

Comment: I can't see why the range would be from x - (d^2 - y^2) , to x + (d^2 - y^2)

Comment: @LanceHAOH look at my drawing, from point (x,y) , we draw two lines to the Ox axis, so that the distance from the intersections of this two lines with Ox to point (x,y) is `d`, so what is the position of those two intersections?

Comment: Oh. I see it now. the two intersections would be x - (d^2 - y^2) and x + (d^2 - y^2). The pyth. theorem will find out the position of the furthest left/right radar with coverage radius of d to cover the island.

Comment: Correction:
A = x - (d^2 + y^2)
B = x + (d^2 + y^2)